# Multiply two textbox value and then show in a label

Tags: asp.net

I got a error In this code ....This is simple but I did not getting what mistake i did

```
"lblSubtotal1.Text=Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtQty1.Text)*Convert.ToDouble(txtUnit1.Text))
```

Comment: Please tell me which error you got?

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What values are you entering in the textboxes?

Comment: 5 and 5 and I am using event of textbox ontextchanged

Comment: Consider using more validation, and using two var's, then try parse those textboxes, then multiply the two vars that you added the two numbers to, and then convert that to a toString() and that will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQty1.Text) AndAlso  Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUnit1.Text) Then
    lblSubtotal1.Text=Convert.ToDouble(txtQty1.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtUnit1.Text)
Else
    lblSubtotal1.Text=String.Empty
End If
```

If its C# then,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQty1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUnit1.Text)) {
    lblSubtotal1.Text = Convert.ToDouble(txtQty1.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtUnit1.Text);
} else {
    lblSubtotal1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

**Updated:**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQty1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUnit1.Text)) {
    double qty=0;
    Double.TryParse(txtQty1.Text, out qty);

    double unit=0;
    Double.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, out unit);

    lblSubtotal1.Text = qty * unit
} 
else {
    lblSubtotal1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
int firstvalue, secValue;
    if (double.TryParse(firsttxt.Text, out firstvalue) && double.TryParse(secTxt.Text, out secValue))
    {
        Lable.Text = (firstvalue*secValue).ToString();
    }
```

I just given you hint, you can Modify the code as your requirement

for more information on  `double.TryParse` you can try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
lblSubtotal1.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtQty1.Text)*(Convert.ToDouble(txtUnit1.Text))).ToString();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.